# how to create a unique hash byte value across each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [GroupID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [PromoNUM] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [P_key] AS (HASHBYTES('md5', 'Sample String to hash ')) PERSISTED
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The `p_key` value has to be unique across each record in the table

Comment: the output is currently a duplicated value across all the records. I mean the same value across all the records

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This may not be the best approach.

Comment: If you actually use this calculation you're hashing the same hard-coded value for each row and this results in the same hash value, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a unique value in each record, use `identity`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] (
    TestId IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [GroupID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [PromoNUM] [FLOAT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

You cannot guarantee that a hashed value will be unique.  You can arrange things so there is a very, very low probability of collision.  But for uniqueness, that may not be good enough.

So, just use the standard method of `IDENTITY`.  Or, if you want a value that is not sequential, use `NEWID()` (however -- I would recommend not using it for a clustered index).

Answer (score 0):

While i agree with Gordon's answer, following is what you probably want to try.

```
[P_key] varbinary(8000) default CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8000)
```

Consider the default random values (`NEWID()`, `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`, `RAND()`) are not good idea for clustered index/Primary key as those are potential fragmentation causes. Instead, use `BIGINT` data-type with `IDENTITY`  or (if really needed) `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data-type with default value as `NEWSEQUENTIALID ()`